# change function so it replace space in a string with a middle case "-"

Tags: c

i was given this program instead of printing "-" at places with space,to change the function so it replaces permnantly the space with "-":

```
#include<stdio.h>
void sp_to_dash(const char *s);
int main(){
sp_to_dash("this is a test");//using the function
return 0;
}//end of main
void sp_to_dash(const char *str){//start of the function
while(*str){//start of while

      if(*str==' ')printf("%c",'-');
      else printf("%c",*str);
      str++;
    }//end of while
}//end of function
```

and i actually did change it and it worked but in a smiliar way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
  void sp_to_dash(char *s);
  int main() {
      char str[] = "this is a test";
      sp_to_dash(str);
      printf("%s", str);
      getchar();
  return 0;
}//end of main
void sp_to_dash(char *str){
while (*str) {
    if (*str == ' ') *str= '-';
    str++;
    }//enf of while
}//end of sp_to_dash
```

now i dont understand something,in the original code (unchanged one) i sent to the function an immediate string and it accepted it however in the second code(changed one)
i had to create a new string for it to accept:

```
char str[]="this is a test";
```

why i could not do something similar to this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 void sp_to_dash(char *s);
  int main() {
    sp_to_dash("this is a string");
  return 0;
 }//end of main
 void sp_to_dash(char *str){
 while (*str) {
     if (*str == ' ') *str= '-';
    str++;
  }//enf of while
}//end of sp_to_dash
```

Comment: String literals are read only, search that in SO and/or google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because string literals are defined as `const char *`, which means you are not allowed to modify it's content. I believe you got some compilation error like *"cannot convert `const char *` to `char *`"*. In such cases it is better not try to fool the compiler by casting to `(char *)` because it will lead to undefined behavior.

Once you defined your string as `char str[]="this is a test";`, you actually created an array of `char`s and initialized it to contain the letters of *"this is a test"* accordingly (with `\0` at the end).

The type of the pointer to any element in this array is `char *` so the compilation passed successfully.